How to set image from Sitecore media librarary as an element's background image in Sitecore XP?
I am looking to set an image from the Sitecore media library as the background image of a  element. Currently, I am able to retrieve the image using an  tag or an image field, as demonstrated below:
<image mediaid="{1551EAFF-E652-5213-BB93-5CB00B4EBC26}" />

However, I would like to know how to configure this specific image as the background image for an HTML element, as shown in the following example:
<div style="background-image: url('');">
  ...
</div>


You can use something like:
<div style="background-image: url('@(Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(Model.Item.Fields["Background Image"].Item))');">
</div>

or
@{
    var backgroundImageField = Model.Item.Fields["Background Image"];
    var imageUrl = string.Empty;

    if (backgroundImageField != null && backgroundImageField.Item != null)
    {
        var mediaItem = (Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem)backgroundImageField.Item;
        imageUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem);
    }
}
<div style="background-image: url('@imageUrl');"></div>


Thank you . If I may ask, where to learn all this? I am learning Sitecore, but not many resources are available, and documentation doesn't seem to be helping much.

You can below code snippet to fetch image url from the media field in Sitecore.

var item = // The item from which you are fetching image field
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imageField = item.Fields["{{ImageFieldName}}"];
string imageUrl = string.Empty;
if (imageField != null && imageField.MediaItem != null)
{
   imageUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageField.MediaItem);
}

Using above way, you can read the image url from the image field and set it as background image inside the view file.
<div style="background-image: url('@imageUrl');">
  ...
</div>

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Thank you . If I may ask, where to learn all this? I am learning Sitecore, but not many resources are available, and documentation doesn't seem to be helping much.
